# USB bus port number vs USB physical position

Tags: linux, usb, usb-device

I have multiple devices connected to 3 USB ports.

I can list them connected with some identification numbers through the following commands:

```
# cd /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb
# ls
1-1     1-1.2   1-1.3   1-1.4   bind    uevent  unbind  usb1    usb2
# cat 1-1.2/product
My Connected Device
```

I want to put a label in the physical port of "My Connected Device" like "Connect Here". And I need to ensure that the following unbind/bind command can be sent only to that port to that specific device:

```
echo -n "1-1.2" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

If the hardware is the same, is it reliable to consider that after a reboot the system will **always** assign 1-1.2 to the same **physical** USB port?

Comment: Your title appears to be incomplete. If it's complete, I think some explanation is warranted.

Comment: Fixed! Was that the only reason for the -1?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Did you mean `vs` instead of `x`?

Comment: Logically it should be so. Why don't you test it?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha I've already tested a couple of times but I think it can't be enough to ensure that it will **always** do that way, because it's some kind of hardware stuff, I don't know which order things are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your USB hardware doesn't change (e.g: USB hubs, USB cards, etc), then **yes**, it is safe to assume that indeed the device will be assigned to the same location in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/x-x.x`. Linux should scan for and assign those x-x.x IDs in the same order every boot, however bear in mind that a device has to be connected to that port for that directory entry to exist.

Answer (score 2):

Usb hosts are basically PCI devices and those are initilized using the same initial enumeration if it adheres to PCI specification. So short answer is yes.

Comment: I understand that for /dev and **connected** devices, it won't generate the same /dev/fooXX, but is that the same for USB bus ports?

Comment: Now I understood your question...Usb hosts are basically PCI devices and those are initilized using the same initial enumeration if it adheres to PCI specification. So short answer is yes.

Comment: So the USB physical ports are **not** guaranteed to have the same 1-1.2 or 1-1.3 assigned in the same hardware?

Comment: It seems I wasn't clear in my answer. They are guaranteed to use always the same interface identifier.

Comment: Ah ok!! Could you please edit your answer?